How to add USING TTL to query with Datastax querybuilder (4.17.0 Java Driver)
I want to generate query like "INSERT INTO table1 (id, data) VALUES (:id, :data) USING TTL :ttl"
with Datastax Cassandra driver QueryBuilder.insertInto().
Other related questions are so old and related to old driver so I wanted to post new
I have already tried something like:
RegularInsert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("table1")
.value("id", QueryBuilder.literal("someid"))
.value("data", QueryBuilder.literal("somedata"));

insert.usingTtl(bindMarker("ttl"));

SimpleStatement simple = insert.build().setExecutionProfileName(CassandraClient.SAFE_OPTIONS_PROFILE);

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = context.getCassandraClient().getSession().prepare(simpleStatement);

BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind().setInt("ttl", ttl);

CompletionStage<AsyncResultSet> future = context.getCassandraClient().getSession().executeAsync(boundStatement);

But looks like USING is not added to query because I get error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ttl is not a variable in this bound statement
What I'm missing or is there bug in Datastax Java driver? Driver version 4.17.0
UPDATE:
My current hack is injecting USING TTL with code like:
String cqlQueryWithTtl = insert.asCql() + " USING TTL " + ttl;
Also noticed that in other parts in our code usingTtl() works but not in this particular case. Strange
